# Call a method in different activities from a non-activity class

Tags: java, android

I have 3 classes with the same function. The class H is a controller class, so i have made a setactivity class to get the instance of the activity that called it. Now i have to call the function userleft() of the currently initialized class from the controller class H which is a non Activity.

The error i am getting is "The method userleft() is undefined for the type Activity" and i know that the exception would come, since the class Activity does not contain a method called userLeft(). But what is the best way to make this work?

See the structure of the app below.

```
public class A extends Activity {

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        H.getInstance().setactivity(this);
    }

    public void userleft() {

    }
}

public class B extends Activity {

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        H.getInstance().setactivity(this);
    }

    public void userleft() {

    }
}

public class C extends Activity {

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        H.getInstance().setactivity(this);
    }

    public void userleft() {

    }
}
```

and i have another non activity class

```
public class H {
    public static H getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new H();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
        this.activityGame = activity;
    }
    public void randomCallBack(){
        activityGame.userleft(); 
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your randomCallBack() method you have an Activity object, the class Activity does not contain a method called userLeft(), so it is normal that you get such an exception. So, you have two ways of solving this issue:

Either, you cast the activityGame to its corresponding class as:

```
 public void randomCallBack(){
    if (activityGame instanceof A) {
           ((A)activityGame).userleft(); 
    }
    if (activityGame instanceof B) {
           ((B)activityGame).userleft(); 
    }
    if (activityGame instanceof C) {
           ((C)activityGame).userleft(); 
    }
}
```

Or, in a better way, you create an Interface, which is implemented by your clasess A, B, and C, and used by H class. Like this:

```
public interface UserLeft {
  public void userleft();
}

public class A extends Activity implements UserLeft {

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    H.getInstance().setactivity(this);
}

public void userleft() {

}
}

public class B extends Activity implements UserLeft {

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    H.getInstance().setactivity(this);
}

public void userleft() {

}
}

public class C extends Activity implements UserLeft {

void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    H.getInstance().setactivity(this);
}

public void userleft() {

}
}

public class H {
UserLeft activity;
public static H getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new H();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void setActivity(UserLeft activity) {
    this.activityGame = activity;
}
public void randomCallBack(){
    activityGame.userleft(); 
}
}
```

Comment: @SanjuSonyKurian That's the one that I would use. Glad it suited you!

Answer (score 3):

You need to redesign your classes like below

Declaire a base activity class

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    public abstract void userleft();
}
```

And declare your classes like

```
public class A extends BaseActivity {

    void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        H.getInstance().setactivity(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void userleft() {

    }
}
```

And now modify your Non-activity class like

```
public class H {
    public static H getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new H();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void setActivity(BaseActivity activity) {
        this.activityGame = activity;
    }
    public void randomCallBack(){
        activityGame.userleft(); 
    }
}
```

Now you will be able to call your method for any subclass activity.

Answer (score 0):

You forgott your instance variable declaration :) `private Activity activityGame = null;`

Of course class **[Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)** has no method called `userleft()`.
You need to **cast** your variable `activityGame` to your specific Class like that:

```
public class H {
  private Activity activityGame = null;

  public static H getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new H();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
    this.activityGame = (<CAST TO YOUR CLASS>) activity;
  }
  public void randomCallBack(){
    activityGame.userleft(); 
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Please try this:

```
public void setActivity(Activity activity) {
  this.activityGame = (activity.getClass()) activity;
}
```

Comment: The activity that calls this class maybe any one of the 3 and it is random. So i cant cast the variable to one particular class and that is the issue basically. :(

Comment: you basically need to create a switch-case. i already think about another way but currently evalutating

Comment: Found a more elegant way of solving it as suggested by @pankaj. :) Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Activity class does not have the method of userleft , so that you can't call that method by the reference activity . You can define one BaseActivity with the method userleft as the parent class of these classes.